# Format output to 40 characters long per line

Tags: ruby, format, line

I'm fairly new to Ruby and I've been searching Google for a few hours now.
Does anyone know how to format the output of a print to be no more than 40 characters long?

For example:

**What I want to print:**

```
This is a simple sentence.
This simple
sentence appears
on four lines.
```

**But I want it formatted as:**

```
This is a simple sentence. This simple
sentence appears on four lines.
```

I have each line of the original put into an array. 
so `x = ["This is a simple sentence.", "This simple", "sentence appears", "on three lines."]`
I tried `x.each { |n| print n[0..40], " " }` but it didn't seem to do anything.

Any help would be fantastic!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `word_wrap` expects a Strind and makes a kind of pretty print.

Your array is converted to a string with  `join("\n")`

The code:

```
def word_wrap(text, line_width = 40 ) 
  return text if line_width <= 0
  text.gsub(/\n/, ' ').gsub(/(.{1,#{line_width}})(\s+|$)/, "\\1\n").strip
end

x = ["This is a simple sentence.", "This simple", "sentence appears", "on three lines."]

puts word_wrap(x.join("\n"))
x << 'a' * 50 #To show what happens with long words
x << 'end'
puts word_wrap(x.join("\n"))
```

Code explanation:

`x.join("\n"))` build a string, then build one long line with `text.gsub(/\n/, ' ')`.
In this special case this two steps could be merged: `x.join(" "))`

And now the *magic* happens with

```
gsub(/(.{1,#{line_width}})(\s+|$)/, "\\1\n")
```

- `(.{1,#{line_width}})`): Take any character up to `line_width` characters.
- `(\s+|$)`: The next character must be a space or line end (in other words: the previous match may be shorter the `line_width` if the last character is no space.
- `"\\1\n"`: Take the up to 40 character long string and finish it with a newline.
- `gsub` repeat the wrapping until it is finished.

And in the end, I delete leading and trailing spaces with `strip`

I added also a long word (50 a's). What happens? The gsub does not match, the word keeps as it is.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense for the most part. What's some of the gsub stuff doing, though? I got the first one but gsub(/(.{1,#{line_width}})(\s+|$)/, "\\1\n") is kind of confusing. Can you explain what's going on here?    (It works perfectly, btw)

Comment: That is what does the actual line wrapping. the \1 is the back reference to what was found in the match group (whats between the "()" in the regexp). {1,40} is a way of setting the length of the match. #{line_width} is rubys string replace variable which is available in regexps as well as double quoted strings.

Answer (score 3):

```
puts x.join(" ").scan(/(.{1,40})(?:\s|$)/m)
```

> This is a simple sentence. This simple
>   sentence appears on three lines.

Comment: Very nice (though arcane). I'll note that the result is a an array, so if you want to get it to a string, you have to .flatten.join the result.

Comment: @M.AnthonyAiello, no need of `.flatten` before `.join`.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby 1.9 (and not overly efficient):

```
>> x.join(" ").each_char.each_slice(40).to_a.map(&:join)
=> ["This is a simple sentence. This simple s", "entence appears on three lines."]
```

The reason your solution doesn't work is that all the individual strings are shorter than 40 characters, so `n[0..40]` always is the entire string.