# Ruby max width output

Tags: ruby

I have an array of strings that I need to print joined by a space in a way that each line only shows a maximum of 80 characters (including the space) per line.

So for example if I have:

```
str_ary = ["I", "am", "an", "array", "of", "strings"]
max_width = 10
```

I should obtain:

```
I am an
array of  
strings
```

Comment: Could you clarify a bit further?

Comment: for instance. if i have an a = ["this", "is", "jon", "doe", "and", "this", "is", "ruby"] how can I print it out to read, 
`code`
this is jon doe
and this is ruby
`code`

Comment: Amazingly, I think I understand what you mean now.

Comment: sorry for the formatting error. any suggestions

Comment: Do you mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548968/format-output-to-40-characters-long-per-line/7549032#7549032 ?

Comment: @melon74: Please clarify your question. Better put the example input/output into the question and format it to show what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you mean?

```
words = %w(foo bar baz quux moomin snufkin fred)
max_width = 11
lines = []

until words.empty?
  width = -1 # The first word needs no space before it.
  line, words = words.partition do |word|
    (width += word.size + 1) <= max_width
  end
  lines << line
end

for line in lines
  puts line.join(" ")
end
```

Output:

```
foo bar baz
quux moomin
snufkin
fred
```

Comment: is there a way to do this without any iterators except using block iterators such as .each

Comment: What do you mean by iterator? Is `until` an iterator? Is `#partition` an iterator?

Comment: and would it be better/easier to modify the array if i started with array, a = [foo bar baz quuz moomin snufkin fred].

Comment: until is an iterator. for, while are as well

Comment: `for` is the exact same as `#each`, apart from syntax.

Comment: And I don’t see the difference between your `a = [foo bar baz quuz moomin snufkin fred]` and what I did (assuming you meant to quote the words).

Answer (score 0):

```
words = %w(foo bar baz quux moomin snufkin fred)
```

assumming max_length is 15 ..

```
irb(main):147:0> words.inject([[]]) do |memo, word|
irb(main):148:1*   (memo.last.join(' ').length + word.length < 15) ? memo.last << word : memo << [word]
irb(main):149:1>   memo
irb(main):150:1> end
=> [["foo", "bar", "baz"], ["quux", "moomin"], ["snufkin", "fred"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it accounting for the spaces:

```
words = %w(this is jon doe and this is ruby)
max_width = 11

lines = ['']
words.each do |word|
    if (lines.last + word).size < max_width
        lines[-1] += (lines.last.empty? ? word : " #{word}")
    else
        lines << word
    end
end

p lines
```