# Insert newline ONLY at word breaks such that no line exceeds 80 chars

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have various blocks of text of variable length that may or may not already have several line breaks in them. I want to take each line of this text, and insert additional newlines but ONLY at word-breaks (spaces) so that no line exceeds 80 chars. They can be under 80, but I want them as close to 80 characters as possible without going over, and without chopping a word in half.

Here's what some sample content might look like:

```
"""
Mittens the cat ate a salad on Friday morning. He's a cat, so I'm not really sure why he was eating a salad, but that's what he was doing. Do cats normally like salad? It wasn't salmon-flavored or anything crazy like that.

I can think of three reasons why a cat might eat salad:
1. The cat is insane
2. The cat likes mice, and just last week we noticed that a mice was eating some salad, so maybe the cat decided to shortcut the food chain and eat a salad instead of getting the nutrients of the salad from the consumption of the mouse.
3. Cats are weird.
"""
```

And after running the newline-inserter, it would come out like this:

```
"""
Mittens the cat ate a salad on Friday morning. He's a cat, so I'm not really
sure why he was eating a salad, but that's what he was doing. Do cats normally
like salad? It wasn't salmon-flavored or anything crazy like that.

I can think of three reasons why a cat might eat salad:
1. The cat is insane
2. The cat likes mice, and just last week we noticed that a mice was eating some
salad, so maybe the cat decided to shortcut the food chain and eat a salad
instead of getting the nutrients of the salad from the consumption of the mouse.
3. Cats are weird.
"""
```

I found several questions solving the (frankly trivial) problem of adding a newline at exactly N characters. I know that I can split on space and *count* the characters and backtrack to add a newline if a line exceeds 80 characters, but that's tedious and not quite the "elegant" solution I'm looking for ;p

I'll go that route if I can't figure out a better way, though.... I guess.

My gut tells me there's a good solution for this using regex and look-aheads/look-behinds.

This is what I have so far:

```
content = """
this is some content with words and stuff
and here is another line things
"""
content = content.gsub(%r{(.{10}) }, "\\1\n")
puts content
```

Which outputs:

```
this is some
content with
words and stuff
and here is
another line
things
```

But it's letting the lines go barely *above* 10 chars, instead of barely below it.

Comment: Lookarounds won't work so well here.

Comment: I'm somewhat curious about the two close votes here. My question seems pretty concise and clear, what, might I ask, is "too broad" about it? It's quite a specific question.

Comment: Regex might not be the best tool for this job.  I might look into using a parser.  The problem here is that the text is not regular, and you don't know how many words to consume until you have gone over the limit, and backtracked.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548968/format-output-to-40-characters-long-per-line/

Answer (score 2):

The Rails way:

```
puts content.gsub(/(.{1,10})(?:\s+|$)/, "\\1\n")
# >>this is
# >>some
# >>content
# >>with words
# >>and stuff
# >>and here
# >>is another
# >>line
# >>things
```

Cf. https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/word_wrap

Comment: This looks promising. I'm doing christmas breaky things right now but I'll give this a whirl in my project when I get back to it and see how it stacks up :) One of the comments in that apidock page says that it might consume multiple newlines, but this regex is a little different than the `collect` that's in the source there. I'll play with it and let you know :)

Comment: nzifnab, sawa's still waiting... If any of the answers have been helpful please consider selecting one.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going w/ the word-traversal route:

```
def wordwrap(content, line_length)
  words = content.scan(/(?:\A|\s)[^\s]*/)
  remaining = line_length
  words.each do |word|
    if word.length > remaining
      word.gsub!(/^\s/, "")
      remaining = line_length - word.length
      word.insert(0, "\n")
    else
      if word =~ /^\n/
        remaining = line_length - word.length - 1
      else
        remaining -= word.length
      end
    end
  end

  words.join
end
```

This inserts newlines before words that would otherwise cause the line to exceed `line_length` characters.

It's a little messier than I was hoping for, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

```
r = /.{,80}[\n ]/
```

```
puts content.gsub(r) { |s| s[0..-2] << "\n" }
```

displays the following:

```
Mittens the cat ate a salad on Friday morning. He's a cat, so I'm not really
sure why he was eating a salad, but that's what he was doing. Do cats normally
like salad? It wasn't salmon-flavored or anything crazy like that.

I can think of three reasons why a cat might eat salad:
1. The cat is insane.
2. The cat likes mice, and just last week we noticed that a mice was eating some
salad, so maybe the cat decided to shortcut the food chain and eat a salad
instead of getting the nutrients of the salad from the consumption of the mouse.
3. Cats are weird.
```

The regular expression matches up to 80 characters followed by a newline or space. Regardless of whether that the last character matched is a space or newline, the last character is replaced by a newline in the block.

For this to work the string may not have multiple spaces in a row and the string must end with a newline character (i.e., `"...weird.\n"`). If those conditions may not hold a simple preprocessing step may be warranted:

```
mod_content = content.squeeze(' ').chomp << "\n"
```